# Dojo: Populate tree structure of local json file in webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

```
<!-- load dojo -->
<script src="file:///D:/dojo-release-1.10.4/dojo-release-1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<script>
    require([
        "dojo/dom",
        "dojo/json",
        "dojo/store/Memory",
        "dijit/tree/ObjectStoreModel",
        "dijit/Tree",
        "dojo/text!file:///D:/dojo-release-1.10.4/dojo-release-1.10.4/dojo/data/small.json",
        "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(dom, json, Memory, ObjectStoreModel, Tree, small){
        // set up the store to get the tree data
        var governmentStore = new Memory({
            data: [ json.parse(small) ],
            getChildren: function(object){
                return object.children || [];
            }

        });
```

the problem here is in this code...its not working fine

Comment: "Not working fine" isn't really helpful. What is going wrong ?

Comment: that piece of code is showing me an " Object error".

Comment: exact error  : "NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied"

Comment: Have you checked if your url to the Json-file is correct?

Comment: yes. the url path is correct.....when i paste the url in browser, it shows the small.json content

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `file://` protocol.
You need to setup a local http server (like wamp) and load files using `http://` protocol

Comment: i have used file:// protocol many times to parse the json and its working fine. i dont know why i am getting error this time.

Comment: I believe it falls into the "Same-origin policy". `dojo/text` is doing a `xhr` call which gets blocked by the browser.